# How to create a reg exp to parse such url?

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, url, mxml

So we have `http://127.0.0.1:4773/robot10382.flv?action=read` we need to get out from it `protocol`, ip/`adress`, port, actual `url` (robot10382.flv here) and `actions` (action=read here) how to parse all that into string vars in one reg exp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised that AS3 does not include proper URL parsing facilities.  To put it simply, it is not easy to safely parse a URL using an RE.  [Here's an example of doing it though.](http://flashascript.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/parsing-url-string-with-regular-expressions-regexp-in-actionscript-3/)

Answer (score 2):

`/(\w+)\:\/\/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\:(\d+)\/(\w+)\?(.+)/` : $1 - protocol, $2 - ip, $3 - port, $4 - actual url, $5 - actions
there's also another way:
protocol : `url.split('://')[0]`
ip/domain name : `url.split('://')[1].split(':')[0]` (or if no port specified - `url.split('://')[1].split('/)[0]`
port : `url.split('://')[1].split(':')[1].split('/')[0]`
actual url : `url.split('?')[0].split('/').reverse()[0]`
actions : `url.split('?')[1].split('&')/*the most possible separator imho*/` elements of this array can also be spliced`('=')` to separate variable names and values.
i know there's an opinion that `splice` shouldn't be used, but i think it's just beautiful when used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when passing a file path to a SWF you would like to perform FileExistance check before passing the file to an AS3 class. To do so you want to know if a URI is a file or an http URL or any other URI with specific protocol (moniker).
The following code will tell you if you are dealing with a local full or relative path.

http://younsi.blogspot.com/2009/08/as3-uri-parser-and-code-sequence-to.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).